# How to highlight RegEx matches with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match, highlight

With the code  as the base, is it possible to highlight any matching items without using an extra plug-in?

I'd like to add `style="backgorund: green;"` to the divs where the items were found, so that I can immidiately see them.

The things I've tried so far haven't been working, so I'm hoping some fresh thoughts from outside my brain will do the trick.

```
function finder(items){
    var needed = [
         /* items */
    ];
    var re = new RegExp(needed.join("|"), "i");
    return(items.match(re) != null);
}

var found = finder(document.body.innerHTML);
var output = found ? "found" : "not found";

if(output == 'found') {
    //highlight found array item
}
```

Comment: Related: I did something similar recently: https://github.com/Ralt/regexfiddle

Comment: Do you want to add the style to the div having the text, or create a span around the text found to highlight only it?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I want to add the style to the element containing the find, not create a new element around it. Will look through the answers given so far now to see if there's already something I can work with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed around my code a bit and solved it like this:

```
function finder(items){
    var needed = [
         /* items */
    ];
    var reg = new RegExp(needed.join("|"), "i");
    var found = (textToCheck.match(reg) != null);
    var foundItem = textToCheck.match(reg);
    return [found,foundItem];
}

var found = finder(document.body.innerHTML)[0];
var foundItem = finder(document.body.innerHTML)[1];

if(found === true) {
    $('div:contains('+foundItem+')').css("background", "greenyellow");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel? There are ready solutions for this. Try [this plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html), for instance. Here's the [source code](http://johannburkard.de/resources/Johann/jquery.highlight-4.js) for the plugin. It's literally a few lines of code, so if you really feel like writing your own highlighting engine, you can analyse it to see how the highlighting is performed.

Comment: I've already taken a look at quite a few plug-ins before and none had what I needed, that's why I asked for direct code. Took a look at the source you linked, not quite what I've been looking for. Thanks a lot for trying to help though!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something with a replace()

```
for (var i = 0; i < needed.length; i++) {
    var word = needed[i];
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(word, '<span style="background: #00ff00">' + word + '</span>');
}
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/4kjuw/

Comment: When I open your fiddle I get all kinds of weird alerts. Also, replacing wasn't exactly what I had in mind, as I wanted to style the parent element, not add a span around the text. Thanks a lot for trying to help though.

Answer (score 1):

Using `innerHTML` is evil as it will replace events and triggers generation of the DOM over and over again. I'd recommend to use an existing plugin as there are more pitfalls you will ran into. Have a look at [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) to highlight custom regular expressions.